# Flutter GridView Remove Extra Spacing with all Children of same size

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, flutter-layout

I am a newbie to Flutter and learning it to my own. I just want to show a grid of 4 blocks contains any other widget. But the problem is that I need to show 4 grid children with equal size. Like
11
22

I am doing it like:

```
         Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: GridView(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, childAspectRatio: 1, crossAxisSpacing: 0, mainAxisSpacing: 0),
                  children: [
                    FittedBox(child: Container(color:Colors.deepOrangeAccent,child: Text("Hello"),),fit: BoxFit.fill),
                    FittedBox(child: Container(color:Colors.blue,child: Text("Hello")),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                    FittedBox(child: Container(color:Colors.cyanAccent,child: Text("Hello")),fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                    FittedBox(child: Container(color:Colors.deepOrangeAccent,child: Text("Hello")),fit: BoxFit.fill,)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          )
```

My Screen Shot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I found so far myself is that to provide:

```
 childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1),
```

by doing like this the screen perfectly divided into 4 grid pieces see screen shots below:

[image: Perfect Portrait Mode]

[image: Perfect Landscape Mode]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you would like to split the screen into 4 equal pieces. You can do that with GridView for sure but GridView does not help you out with allocating available space.

You need to use Rows inside a Column and take advantage of the Expanded widget per view. You can check the example below for the code:

You can also run this code on dartpad.dev

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children:  [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(color: Colors.green),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

It will give you the following output.

[image: Result]

Comment: It looks like a workaround because what if the children are dynamic views

Comment: It is not a workaround. That is why I wrote "if I understood your question correctly". Because the question was not clear to me. Since, you said you are a newbie, I wanted to help with an explanatory answer :)